# SI prefixes in ggplot2 axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I often plot graphs in GNU R / ggplot for some measurements related to bytes. The builtin axis labels are either plain numbers or scientific notation, ie 1 Megabyte = 1e6. I would like SI prefixes (Kilo = 1e3, Mega=1e6, Giga=1e9, etc) instead, i.e. axis should be labelled 1.5K, 5K, 1M, 150M, 4G etc.

I currently use the following code:

```
si_num <- function (x) {

  if (!is.na(x)) {
    if (x > 1e6) { 
      chrs <- strsplit(format(x, scientific=12), split="")[[1]];
      rem <- chrs[seq(1,length(chrs)-6)];
      rem <- append(rem, "M");
    }

    else if (x > 1e3) { 
      chrs <- strsplit(format(x, scientific=12), split="")[[1]];
      rem <- chrs[seq(1,length(chrs)-3)];
      rem <- append(rem, "K");
    }
    else {
      return(x);
    }

    return(paste(rem, sep="", collapse=""));
  }
  else return(NA);
} 

si_vec <- function(x) {
  sapply(x, FUN=si_num);
}

library("ggplot2");

bytes=2^seq(0,20) + rnorm(21, 4, 2);
time=bytes/(1e4 + rnorm(21, 100, 3)) + 8;

my_data = data.frame(time, bytes);

p <- ggplot(data=my_data, aes(x=bytes, y=time)) +
     geom_point() +
     geom_line() +
     scale_x_log10("Message Size [Byte]", labels=si_vec) +
     scale_y_continuous("Round-Trip-Time [us]");
p;
```

I would like to know if this solution can be improved, as my one requires a lot of boilerplate code in every graph.

Comment: You could look at `utils:::print.object_size`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I used `library("sos"); findFn("{SI prefix}")` to find the `sitools` package.

Construct data:

```
bytes <- 2^seq(0,20) + rnorm(21, 4, 2)
time <- bytes/(1e4 + rnorm(21, 100, 3)) + 8
my_data <- data.frame(time, bytes)
```

Load packages:

```
library("sitools")
library("ggplot2")
```

Create the plot:

```
(p <- ggplot(data=my_data, aes(x=bytes, y=time)) +
     geom_point() +
     geom_line() +
     scale_x_log10("Message Size [Byte]", labels=f2si) +
     scale_y_continuous("Round-Trip-Time [us]"))
```

I'm not sure how this compares to your function, but at least someone else went to the trouble of writing it ...

I modified your code style a little bit -- semicolons at the ends of lines are harmless but are generally the sign of a MATLAB or C coder ...

**edit**: I initially defined a generic formatting function

```
si_format <- function(...) {
    function(x) f2si(x,...)
}
```

following the format of (e.g) `scales::comma_format`, but that seems unnecessary in  this case -- just part of the deeper `ggplot2` magic that I don't fully understand.

The OP's code gives what seems to me to be not quite the right answer: the rightmost axis tick is "1000K" rather than "1M" -- this can be fixed by changing the `>1e6` test to `>=1e6`.  On the other hand, `f2si` uses lower-case `k` -- I don't know whether `K` is wanted (wrapping the results in `toupper()` could fix this).

OP results (`si_vec`):

[image]

My results (`f2si`):

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** Recent versions of the [`scales`](https://scales.r-lib.org/) package include functionality to print readable labels.

In this case, [`label_bytes`](https://scales.r-lib.org/reference/label_bytes.html) can be used:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

bytes <- 2^seq(0,20) + rnorm(21, 4, 2)

my_data <- data.frame(
    bytes=as.integer(bytes),
    time=bytes / (1e4 + rnorm(21, 100, 3)) + 8
)

ggplot(data=my_data, aes(x=bytes, y=time)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    scale_x_log10("Message Size [Byte]", labels=label_bytes()) +
    scale_y_continuous("Round-Trip-Time [us]")
```

[image: scales-si-labels]

Or, if you prefer to have IEC units (`KiB = 2^10`, `MiB = 2 ^ 20`, ...), specify `labels=label_bytes(units = "auto_binary")`. For the result, check out the second plot in the original answer below as the result is very similar.

---

**Original answer**

For bytes there is [`gdata::humanReadable`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gdata/versions/2.18.0/topics/humanReadable). `humanReadable` supports both SI prefixes (1000 Byte = 1 KB) as well as the [binary prefixes defined by the IEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix) (1024 Byte = 1 KiB).

This function `humanReadableLabs` allows to customise the parameters and takes care of `NA` values:

```r
humanReadableLabs <- function(...) {
    function(x) {
        sapply(x, function(val) {
            if (is.na(val)) {
                return("")
            } else {
                return(
                    humanReadable(val, ...)
                )
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Now it is straightforward to change the labels to use SI prefixes and "byte" as the unit:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gdata)

bytes <- 2^seq(0,20) + rnorm(21, 4, 2)

my_data <- data.frame(
    bytes=as.integer(bytes),
    time=bytes / (1e4 + rnorm(21, 100, 3)) + 8
)

humanReadableLabs <- function(...) {...}

ggplot(data=my_data, aes(x=bytes, y=time)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    scale_x_log10("Message Size [Byte]", labels=humanReadableLabs(standard="SI")) +
    scale_y_continuous("Round-Trip-Time [us]")
```

[image: si-labels]

IEC prefixes are plotted by omitting `standard="SI"`. Note that the breaks would have to be specified as well to have well-legible values.

```r
ggplot(data=my_data, aes(x=bytes, y=time)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    scale_x_log10("Message Size [Byte]", labels=humanReadableLabs()) +
    scale_y_continuous("Round-Trip-Time [us]")
```

[image: iec-labels]