# How to convert large numbers into a letter format (e.g. 1000 = 1k) for x-axis labels in R

Tags: r, format, label

I am generating an x-y plot using R where x-values are large numbers like 
1650000. These are too long to show. How can I just show 1650k instead on the x-axis in a plot.

```
xx <- c(165000,167000,169000,178000,187000)
yy <- 1:5

plot(xx,yy,cex.lab=.5)
```

Comment: Sorry i don't want to use ggplot2. Pls suggest any solution with normal formatting only.

Comment: This is [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973644/si-prefixes-in-ggplot2-axis-labels)

Comment: `plot(xx,yy,  xaxt='n') ;
 axis(1, at=pretty(xx), labels=paste0(pretty(xx)/1000, "K"))`